# Regular Expression to match character appearing at least 10 times anywhere in string

Tags: regex

I'm a novice trying to create a regex to match the '@' symbol appearing at least 10 times anywhere in a string. For example, in 10 or more email addresses.

I figured the easiest way was just to match 10 or more '@' characters like this [@]{10,} but that doesn't work because it's looking for 10 or more consecutive @ characters.

I got a bit lost trying to make it match non-consecutive characters so I need your help please.

Update - Thank you all for your help unfortuantely I can't get any of these to work within MS Exchange Online as it looks like it only supports a limited version of regex... [image: The constraits are below]

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this within these constraints?

Comment: What character(s) separate the 10 email addresses?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow community, can you please share your code with us?

Comment: I've reworded my question a bit but in my use case the email addresses appear in the following format  <autosupport@netapp.com>, <autosupport@proact.co.uk>,
 <itemailalerts@nhg.co.uk>

Comment: in terms of 'my code' i got stuck at /[@]{10,}
/gm but this is obviously no good as looking for concurrent characters

Answer (score 0):

Think of each `@` as being preceded by 0 or more non-`@` characters:

```
[^@]*@
```

Then repeat 10 times:

```
(?:[^@]*@){10}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try to use this in an Exchange Online Mail Rule I get the following message. '|Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.Rules.Tasks.ValidationArgumentException|"Running regular expression '(?:[^@]*@){10}' takes too much CPU time.  Consider using a  less complex pattern."
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PSDirectInvoke.DirectInvokeCmdletExecutionException' was thrown.'

Comment: @Wilholme Makes sense. What exactly are you trying to ascertain here? Maybe there's a non-regex rule type you can use

Comment: I'm trying to create an Exchange Online Mailflow rule that will detect any e-mail with 10 or more recipients in either the To or Cc (mail headers) and send it for review by another person before it is sent out of the organisation.

Comment: @Wilholme that's not going to work either way - the recipient predicates supported in exchange online are only applied to one recipient at a time, not the list as a whole

Answer (score 0):

Add `.*` between `@`:

```
(.*?@){10}
```

The reluctant quantifier `*?` (which matches as *few* characters as possible) makes it more efficient than the familiar greedy `.*` that would backtrack like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

([^@]*@[^@]*){10,} matches at least 10 @ in a string separated by other characters

Comment: The question says *"anywhere in a string"*. This RegEx requires two non-`@` characters between each `@`. Perhaps you meant to use `[^@]*@[^@]*`.